# How to introduce a dynamic counter for enumerate environment?

Tags: enumerate

I would like to use numbers: "1.", "2.", "3.", ... but the last item ("n.") is an exception, instead of "10." for example I would like to use "(9+1).".

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This requires some `\if..` statements for the output of the counter

Answer (score 4):

[**Edit** Making the endpoint "dynamic".]

This looks like a job for [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). More specifically, you can use `\AddEnumerateCounter` to define special processing for an enumerate counter to produce:

[image]

(I've formatted it in two columns to save space.)

The LaTeX code is not too cumbersome. I've defined a new environment called `bracketted`. You use this environment like an ordinary enumerate environment. The difference is that items in a `bracketted` environment are automatically labelled in the way that I think the OP wants them.

In order to make the end-point "dynamic" the `bracketted` environment accepts an optional argument -- which defaults to `9` as in the question -- for specifying where the printing of the counter should change. The `bracketted` environment itself wraps an enumerate-like environment, called `internalbracketted`. This environment is defined using the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and it uses `\AddEnumerateCounter` to change how the item numbers are printed. You can change the formatting of this environment by modifying the `\setlist[internalbracketted]{...}` specifications as described in the `enumitem` manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\AddEnumerateCounter{\SpecialTen}{\SpecialTen}{(9+1)}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\SpecialTen[1]{%
   \ifnum\value{#1}>\specialValue%
     \@tempcnta=\value{#1}\advance\@tempcnta by-\specialValue%
     (\specialValue+\@arabic\@tempcnta)%
     \else\arabic{#1}%
     \fi%
}
\makeatother
\newlist{internalbracketted}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[internalbracketted]{nosep,label=\SpecialTen*.}
\newenvironment{bracketted}[1][9]{\def\specialValue{#1}\internalbracketted}
   {\endinternalbracketted}

\begin{document}\begin{multicols}{2}
  With 3 being special:

  \begin{bracketted}[3]
    \item \item \item \item \item
   \end{bracketted}

  With 4 being special:

  \begin{bracketted}[4]
    \item \item \item \item \item
   \end{bracketted}

   \columnbreak
  With 9 being special (the default):

  \begin{bracketted}    % with no optional argument the special value defaults to 9
    \item \item \item \item \item
    \item \item \item \item \item
  \end{bracketted}

\end{multicols}\end{document}
```

Even though the OP only asked for the last item number to be treated specially this changes all item labels after the "special" value -- you have to do something with them after all and, a priori, there is no way of knowing ahead of time which `\item` is the last one.

It's still not clear to me if this is what the OP wants as the meaning dynamic isn't really explained, but this is might suffice. If the OP wants to automatically detect the last `\item` then this is possible but it would require a different approach. It would help if the OP had provided a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and a better explanation of what they were looking for.

Comment: Why aren't you using `\arabic` for the `(9+` part?

Comment: @daleif I can't use `\arabic` with `\@tempcnta`...actually, to be honest, if I wanted to print it as an `\alph` I don't know how to offhand...I'd have to go searching:)

Comment: ahh, yes of course, it is not stored in naming convention expected by `\arabic`.

Comment: @daleif I figured it out: I've edited the code to use `\@arabic` -- which is what `\arabic` does in LaTeX. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: dynamic means that I dont want to set a fix threshold like 10 in your example, instead I want only the last item to be different

Comment: @user3058699 I've made the solution dynamic. It's not really clear to me from your question that what I have done is "dynamic" in the way that you want it to me. This is why you should include a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve your aim is to have a command `\finalitem` in your enumerate environment and format the last `item` the way you want. This may not be 'dynamic' in the way you wish because it's not automatic, it relies on you as a user to place the `finalitem` command always as the last item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\finalitem{\item[(\theenumi+1.)]}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\item 
\finalitem 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```